# WP sidebar replicated in dashboard window

Tags: menu, wp

Any ideas on why one user may be seeing the WP sidebar replicated over the dashboard. This happens on all browsers (IE, Firefox, Chrome) it only happens for the one user. Her WP role is the same as other users.

Functionality of the rest of the application is fine except for this annoying 'extra' sidebar

[image]

Comment: Can you use an inspector to see what CSS is responsible for this? It would help in debugging the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Found the problem.

Firstly the screen in the image above is not fully loaded.

Once it had loaded the error message "custom field expected (0) found" which pointed to the report it was attempting to load in the dashboard being obsolete.

Deleting the report resolved the problem. :)